# select на всю оставшуюся ширину

Tags: css

Есть контейнер фиксированной ширины. В нем нужно расположить 3 элемента:

Раскрывающийся список `<select>`

Переключатель `<input type="radio">`

Лейбл `<label>` с текстом, привязанный к `<input type="radio">`

Элементы должны идти в одну строку и `<select>` должен быть растянут на всю ширину, не занятую другими элементами, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `width:100%`; ну и `box-sizing:border-box;`.

Comment: Если так то select занимает всю ширину, а переключатель и лейбл переносятся на новую строку.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov покажите код

Comment: У вас, какая-то каша в голове. Вы сами хоть знаете, что хотите? Если да, то покажите нормальный пример и что вас уже есть, иначе, этот вопрос следует закрыть.

Comment: Вопрос решил. Закрыл бы его сам, но не знаю как.

Comment: Здесь принято отвечать и выбирать решение, оформите решение и выберите в качестве ответа.